# Run code when class instance is created

Tags: objective-c

How can I create a class that doesn't have any special parent that calls a function when it is initiated?

Or does it not matter that I am using a UIViewController as a parent for a class that doesn't have a View Controller associated with it?

Comment: All classes have a parent class except `NSObject`...

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you just want to override `init`?

Comment: @nhgrif and `NSProxy`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a class, instead of using `UIViewController` which often comes up as the default super class while building `iOS` apps, change this to `NSObject`.

```
File -> New -> File... -> Cocoa Touch -> Objective-C Class -> Next -> ...
```

Give your class a name and choose **`NSObject`** from the `subclass of` dropdown.

---

Objective-C, unlike many other OOP languages, doesn't have constructors.  Instead, everything that inherits from `NSObject` inherits an `alloc` method (which create memory space on the heap for the instance of the object) and a default `init` method.

You create instances of your object using `[[MyObject alloc] init]` by default, so if you override `init` and put code in here, it will execute when you run `[[MyObject alloc] init]`.  You can create several different `init` methods, and you can even create `factory` methods.  But the basic `init` override should look like this:

```
-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        //do stuff
    }
    return self;
}
```

But I prefer improving this further and writing a `factory` method so I don't have to type out `[[MyObject alloc] init]` every time.  `Factory` methods should be paired with `init` methods that take the same arguments, and they'll look something like this:

```
+(instancetype)myObject{
    return [MyObject alloc] init];
}
```

Now instead of doing:

```
MyObject *a = [[MyObject alloc] init];
```

You can just do this:

```
MyObject *a = [MyObject myObject];
```

This makes more sense with more complicated init methods.  For example, consider:

```
MyDate *today = [[MyDate alloc] initWithYear:2013 month:11 day:14];
```

When we could just do:

```
MyDate *tday = [MyDate dateWithYear:2013 month:11 day:14];
```

And no matter how the `initWithYear:month:day:` method looks, the `factory` method would simply look like this:

```
+(instancetype)dateWithYear:(NSInteger) y month:(NSInteger)m day:(NSInteger)d {
    return [[MyDate alloc] initWithYear:y month:m day:d];
}
```

Comment: Where do I put the code/functions I want to call when the instance is created?

Comment: You have to create your own `init` methods.

Comment: I improved the answer.

Comment: Oh okay that's super easy. I thought their init function did something fancy

Comment: Well... you have to include that pattern, call to `super init`, checking `if(self)`, and `return self;`, but you can just follow that basic pattern and put whatever you want within the `if` block and you're good to go.